# PHP 7.4 and HTML_Quickform 1.3 to 3.2.16?

Tags: php, pear, php-7.4

currently i have to upgrade a programm that is written on PHP 5 to PHP 7.4 to migrate it into the cloud. But in the code is HTML_Quickform 1.3 used and what i have red is that it is a really old version and deprecated since years and i have to upgrade the version that i can use it together with PHP 7.4. I concidered to use the latest version of Quickform v. 3.2.16 but there are so many changes since 1.3 that i dunno how much much time i need to change the code that the programm can run with the latest Quickform version. I will have to change some thousand lines of code and this could be really time consuming. Cause there are many major changes of classes and and namespaces cause 1.3 hasnt namespaces at all.

Is it worth to go for it or is it only a waste of time?

Would be glad to get some helpfull answers.

Greetings Litle student

Comment: Welcome to the age-old conundrum of software development. :) We can't possibly tell you what to do here, as this is a rather opinionated question. However, when making your decision, please note that the version you're thinking about upgrading to (7.4) is _already_ past its [end of life](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php).

Comment: This will be only a solution for max. a year till we get the new software, the problem is im not clear how much work it will be and is it worth to invest the time for using it max. a year

Comment: You don't technically have to upgrade anything just move to the cloud. There's nothing stopping you from running the outdated software on a container (or a VPS) running PHP 5.